# SystemJS fine-grain dependency loading control

Tags: systemjs

Okay, so I have a project managing module dependencies with SystemJS.

```
  <head>
    <!-- SystemJS -->
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
     System.import('d3.min.js')
     System.import('fisheye.js')
     System.import('awesomplete.js')
     System.import('graph.js')
    </script>
```

Now how may I control the order of module loading other than through the order of the imports above? Is there any fine grain control? Can I control my "main" javascript code to start before or after this or other dependency loaded or am I bound to have it start only after everything loaded? Can the framework in itself log dependency loading timings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

You might nest the imports for order sensitive scripts, but usually it indicates that the code is not ok:

```
//Sequencial loading
System.import('d3.min.js')
   .then(function() {

      //Sequencial loading
      System.import('fisheye.js')
         .then(function() {

             //Parallel loading
             Promise.all([
                 System.import('awesomplete.js'),
                 System.import('graph.js'),  
             ])
               .then(function() {
                   //Loaded
               });
         });
   });
```

#### Solution 2

You might create a script that imports the dependencies in order:

**libs.js**

```
import 'd3.min.js';
import 'fisheye.js';
import 'awesomeplete.js';
import 'graph.js'
```

**index.html**

```
System.import('libs.js');
```